# Android does not resolve local hostname. Computer does

Tags: dns

on my debian server I have an apache instance that I access only in local lan.
Suddenly I cannot connect to it anymore from my android 7.1 phone through hostname. 
Connecting through local ip works from both computers and android phones.
Connecting through hostname only works from computers (windows) but not from android phones.
Where should I look at?

I don't want to edit the host file because I change often networks.

thank you

Comment: I'd start with the settings. Assuming you're talking about WiFi here, check the WiFi AP, in "advanced settings", and look what DNS servers are configured. Compare that with what your computers use. If it's different, edit it accordingly on the Android device.

Comment: +1 Did you ever figure it out? I just noticed your similar question after posting mine: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230644/22600 I wonder if the same was true for you where removing .local could get it to work. I am trying to figure out how to get the .local address to work on Android too since that's how it works for all other devices.